# git pull cause uncommited changes

Tags: git

I cloned a repository from Gitlab and then did `git pull origin master`, then switched to anther branch `branchA`. I later did `git pull origin branchA`, this causes a few files in my local became unstaged, however I didn't make any of these changes, they're all the files committed by others, and if I pull it again, git prompt me to "merge branchA into BranchA", why is that?

Comment: Maybe some other program is auto-updating your files? Using Sublime, LESS/SASS compiler or other program that may work in background?

Comment: @Justinas no， not in this case.

Comment: Maybe my answer here could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871938/unstaged-changes-immediately-after-cloning-in-eclipse/30118841#30118841

Comment: Have you pushed the newly created branch to origin? Have you set an upstream to the new branch?

Comment: @VighIosif i didnt create a new branch. just switched to an existing  branch.

Comment: @ckruczek its not a line ending issue, all the devs are using OS X, and these files are not just like modified, some of them are untracked, like added by myself, but i didnt do anything, still in that branch.

Comment: Sounds like a merge conflict - did you get a message about a conflict when you did `git pull`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you made pull from working copy, so files has been modified meanwhile.

Comment: the last commit in branchA is two hours ago, the files all become uncommited in my local, some are even untracked, which means it's impossible that i modified it.